# Javascript Discord Bot 'SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, discord.js

I've been trying to create a discord bot that filters certain words and then sends a message afterwards. Here is my current code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

//runs the message looker thingy
client.on('message', async message function {
  //1 blacklisted words
  let blacklisted = ['communism', 'fascism', 'socialism', 'conservatism', 'racism', 'sexism', 'nazism', 'marxism'] //words put , after the word

  //2 looking for words
  let foundInText = false;
  for (var i in blacklisted) { // loops through the blacklisted list
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
  }
  // checks casesensitive words

  //3 deletes and send message
    if (foundInText) {
      message.delete();
      client.message.send('ISM SPOTTED. OFFICIAL ISM REPORT HAS BEEN FILED AND WILL BE OVERLOOKED BY THE HIGH ISM COUNCIL. ANYTHING YOU SAY CAN AND WILL BE USED AGAINST YOU IN A COURT OF LAW. YOUR FATE SHALL BE DETERMINED.');
    }
});
```

However I keep experiencing an error saying:

```
client.on('message', async message function {
                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I have placed an end bracket everywhere in the line of code and it still doesn't work. Can someone please explain the error and tell me what to do to fix it?

Comment: `async message function {` should be `async message => {`. That's just not valid syntax in any version of JavaScript.

Comment: Or `async message => {`, if you're sticking with arrow functions, like the 'ready' code.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

A function definition needs to have parentheses for its arguments, even if there are none.

```
function(){}
```